# How to get FormGroup from ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-directive, projection, angular-forms

There is a component that uses a panel with a nested panel-content in which a formGroup can be created

```
       <panel>
            <panel-header>
                <div class="title">{{subgroup.name}}</div>
            </panel-header>
            <panel-content>
                <simple-group-card [group]="subgroup"></app-simple-group-draft-claim-card>
            </panel-content>
        </panel>
```

In turn, in the panel component, the child components panel-header and panel-content are projected through ng-content

```
<ng-content select="panel-header"></ng-content>
<div class="panel-content" *ngIf="promoted">
  <ng-content select="panel-content"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I get the component object that contains the FormGroup (I look through the console.log)

```
    PanelContentComponent {__ngContext__: LEmbeddedView_SimpleGroupCardComponent_ng_container_1_ng_container_1(75)}
__ngContext__: LEmbeddedView_SimpleGroupCardComponent_ng_container_1_ng_container_1(75)
  0: simple-group-card
  1: TView {type: 2, blueprint: LViewBlueprint(75), queries: TQueries_, viewQuery: null, template: 
  ...
  28: FormGroup {_hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator: false, _parent: null, pristine: true, touched: false, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
```

How do I get a link to this FormGroup?
This approach doesn't work:

```
@ContentChild(PanelContentComponent, {static: true, read: FormGroup})
private _content;
```

It is necessary to find out if the FormGroup is present in the component

Comment: i think you could use a common interface for child content component that has a method to `getForms()`